# Another "update on popbackstack" topic

Tags: android-fragments, android-listview, android, android-lifecycle

There are dozens of this kind of threads, but i couldnt find and solution for my problem (at least working one).

So i have 3 fragments in my viewpager, my last (3rd) fragment is basically a friendlist, i also have a button with which i open a new fragment, where i handle search/request etc. In that fragment i have "back button", i get back to my "3rd" fragment in a viewpager with getFragmentManager().popBackStack(). How can i pass boolean value or something back to the "3rd" fragment?

I tried with manually calling onPause and onResume methods of the 3rd fragment, but then my list is empty. Also no methods of the 3rd fragment is called when i popbackstack.

This is my code

3rd fragment

This is how i open new fragment

```
    ImageButton friendsButton = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.friendsButton);
    friendsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SearchActivity configDetailSectionFragment = new SearchActivity();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.item_detail_container, configDetailSectionFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

and this is how i get back to the 3rd fragment

```
    ImageButton backButton=(ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

        } });
```

My methods for filling exlistview work fine, just no methods are called after popbackstack, so i could update my list.

What should i change and when and where should i call listadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: You can call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() every time the fragment is resumed, so always the new data is displayed.

Comment: Im using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), but onResume is not called when i use popbackstack(), thats the problem.

Comment: Probably it's because you are _adding_ the fragment instead of _replacing_ it, so onResume is not called. What you have to do is to get a reference to the previous fragment (via fragmentManager.findFragmentById()) and then call a custom method to refresh the adapter.

Comment: I'll try that, this is bothering me for a while what id should i use in "findFragmentById(X)" method? Layout of my fragment?

Comment: _X_ in this case is the _tag_ of the fragment you have to find, and it's the _tag_ you passed to the method _public abstract FragmentTransaction add (int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)_.

Comment: Oh ok, i wasnt aware of this string tag option, thanks! But when i add tag to my add method, i actually give tag to a new fragment not "friendlist" fragment. Is there any option to assign tag name to fragments in a viewpager?

Comment: I don't know if this is a possible scenario, because fragments in a ViewPager are handled via FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Comment: From my logs i can see my methods are called, just visually nothing happens. http://pastebin.com/FTVagikY  I also replaced add for replace method. Do you have any suggestion how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think this is the right way to get fragments from a ViewPager. Better if you store all the fragments instantied in a list and get the item from that list.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52578/discussion-between-mattia-franchetto-and-gregaj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using add fragment method with addBackStack, on poBackStack previous fragment's onResume will not get called. So if you are using addBackStack and popBackStack, and you want to call onResume of your previous fragment then you have to use replace instead of add. So your code just changes like - 
     **transaction.replace(R.id.item_detail_container,configDetailSectionFragment);**

once you did this you can use your onResume method to refresh list.